# div not generated new line if content has no space.

Tags: css

I made a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bexoss/b6ba4kjg/

I'm trying to make comment form and will show comment to div, but If the div content has no space, new line would't generated so the content has long width and short height.

I give to div to style such as `white-space: pre-wrap` but it doesn't solve this problem, could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: [Here is your answer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the word-wrap property to your css

```
.div1 { 
    width: 300px; 
    margin-bottom:50px; 
    background-color: yellow; 
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b6ba4kjg/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```